# Generic protocol functions & lvalue in swift

Tags: swift, closures, protocols

I am encountering the following error when I try to call a stored closure.  I get this error when I try to build:

'(T) -> Void' is not convertible to '@lvalue (T) -> Void' (aka '@lvalue (T) -> ()')

```
public protocol DataSourceProtocol {
  associatedtype DataSourceItem

  func item(indexPath: IndexPath) -> DataSourceItem?
  func update<T>(sender : T)
}

public class AnyDataSourceSimple<T> : DataSourceProtocol {
  private var itemClosure : (IndexPath) -> T?
  private var updateClosure: (T) -> Void

  public init<I: DataSourceProtocol>(_ concrete: I) where I.DataSourceItem == T {
    self.itemClosure = concrete.item
    self.updateClosure = concrete.update
}

public func item(indexPath: IndexPath) -> T? {
    return itemClosure(indexPath)
}

public func update<T>(sender: T) {
    // '(T) -> Void' is not convertible to '@lvalue (T) -> Void' (aka '@lvalue (T) -> ()')
    updateClosure(sender)   
    print("update")
  }
}
```

Is this somehow related to a generic function definition within a protocol?

Comment: You're defining a new local generic placeholder `T` in your `update` function, which is completely unrelated to your `AnyDataSourceSimple`'s `T`. Just remove it from the function (and then update your protocol so `update` takes a `DataSourceItem` parameter).

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40442497/2976878

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments, your `T` for generic function is separate for the `T` in the definition of the generic class.

To make it compile you have to do it like this, not sure if this is what you meant

```
import Foundation

public protocol DataSourceProtocol {
    associatedtype DataSourceItem
    associatedtype UpdateSender

    func item(indexPath: IndexPath) -> DataSourceItem?
    func update(sender : UpdateSender)
}

public class AnyDataSourceSimple<T> : DataSourceProtocol {
    private var itemClosure : (IndexPath) -> T?
    private var updateClosure: (T) -> Void

    public init<I: DataSourceProtocol>(_ concrete: I) where I.DataSourceItem == T, I.UpdateSender == T {
        self.itemClosure = concrete.item
        self.updateClosure = concrete.update
    }

    public func item(indexPath: IndexPath) -> T? {
        return itemClosure(indexPath)
    }

    public func update(sender: T) {
        updateClosure(sender)   
        print("update")
    }
}
```