# Swift generics Bool is not convertible to Bool

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have written a protocol like:

```
public protocol Protocol1 {
    func execute<T, R>(req: T) -> Promise<R>
}
```

Implemented the protocol as Below:

```
struct Implemented1 : Protocol1 {
    func execute<String, Bool>(req : String) -> Promise<Bool> {
        return Promise<Bool>() { fulfill, reject in
           fulfill(true)
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting following error:

**'Bool' is not convertible to 'Bool'**

Please help me to understand what is the issue.

Comment: Where is the error appearing? At the promise? Where is Promise defined?

Comment: @NateBirkholz The error is coming at fulfill(true). and Promise is from PromiseKit

Comment: Can you show the definition of `Promise`? Just the initializer should be fine.

Comment: @Sweeper Promise definition is at https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit

Comment: Try fulfill(value: true)

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth sorry but that didn't worked

Comment: What happened?  Was it the same result?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth fulfill didnot supported this kind of declaration and asked to remove value:

Comment: My bad I must have misread the source code.  I'm off to play football now but will take another look later.

Comment: Compare [Swift Generic Protocol Function Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40442497/2976878)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is at the start of the method declaration.

```
func execute<String, Bool>
```

Who taught you to declare a generic method this way?

The generic parameters are supposed to go in the `<>`s, not actual types!

To implement the protocol, you need a generic method, not one that accepts a `String` and returns `Bool`.

So the compiler treats `String` and `Bool` as names of the generic parameters, instead of the actual swift types. So when the compiler says that `Bool` cannot be converted to `Bool`, it actually means that the swift `Bool` type cannot be converted to the generic parameter `Bool`.

I think what you need is associated types.

```
public protocol Protocol1 {
    associatedtype RequestType
    associatedtype ResultType
    func execute(req: RequestType) -> Promise<ResultType>
}

struct Implemented1 : Protocol1 {
    typealias ResultType = Bool
    typealias RequestType = String
    func execute(req : String) -> Promise<Bool> {
        return Promise { fulfill, reject in
            fulfill(true)
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. this:

```
Promise { fulfill, reject in
    fulfill(true)
}
```

can be simplified to:

```
Promise(value: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. i believe generics is something i need to understand more, as I see it worked differently as in C#. I have just started working on swift.

Comment: Just a quick query. How can i add a decorator around this implementation and able to register it in an IOC container with same Service Protocol?

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about IOC containers. I suggest that you do some research yourself first, and post another question. @BalrajSingh